# Is Conservation law of angular momentum not so general?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, reference-frames, angular-momentum, conservation-laws

Consider a mass rotating in a plane around a fixed point O at constant speed.
In such case the angular momentum with respect to O is constant and its time variation is zero according to the fact the torque is zero.But if you change the point to which you evaluate torque and angular momentum, the time derivative of angular momentum is not necessarily zero. So?

Comment: In that case, the torque also will not be zero with respect to the new reference point. You will still have $\frac{dL}{dt} = \tau$.

Answer (score 1):

Intuitively speaking, angular momentum centered at a point $O$ is conserved if the laws of physics don't change when we rotate the system around that point. A more precise, but mathematically more involved way to state this is Noether's theorem (which is quite a bit more general, explaining all kinds of conserved quantities like energy, momentum and others as well).

In your example, there is probably a reason why the mass rotates around the fixed point $O$. Probably because there is a central force pointing towards that point which depends only on the distance to that point. If we rotate the system around that point, we don't change a thing about the physical laws, since the forces are still all pointing to the same point.

But if we rotate the system around a different point $P$, then we change where the forces are pointing, since $O$ is rotated around $P$. So angular momentum centered at $P$ is not conserved.

In the real world, however, the central forces are caused by some object, like the sun, or a charged particle. This object will also rotate around the same point, but with a phase difference of $\pi$. When measuring angular momentum from some point other than $O$, the changes in angular momentum of the two objects orbiting each other will cancel exactly, so that total angular momentum is conserved.

Answer (score 0):

If you talk about angular momentum and conservation of angular momentum it is **essential to specify which reference point (coordinate origin)** you're talking about.

For exapmle think about to coordinate systems $\Sigma = (x,y,z), \ \Sigma' = (x',y'z')$, which are connected to an time-indepedent translation $\vec{R}$ (and thus have different origins):

$\vec{r} = \vec{R} + \vec{r}'$

Computing the angular momentum you get:

$\vec{L} = m\vec{r} \times \frac{d}{dt}\vec{r} = m(\vec{R}+\vec{r}') \times \frac{d}{dt}\vec{r}' = \vec{R} \times \vec{p}' + \vec{L}'$

And thus also $\frac{d}{dt}\vec{L} \neq \frac{d}{dt}\vec{L}'$.

For normal momentum $\vec{p}$ you would get a different result:

$\vec{p} = m\frac{d}{dt}\vec{r} =  m\frac{d}{dt}(\vec{R} + \vec{r}') = m\frac{d}{dt}\vec{r}' = \vec{p}'$

Hence, you have to say **angular momentum is conserved with respect to a certain coordinate origin**. Most of the time if the coordinate origin seems to be obvious, explicity specifying the coorinate origin is left out.